# Getting values from listView in Android to textView or another Listview same activity

Tags: android, listview

@
I'm Trying to populate a textView or Listview based on the selection from another list view. So far I have an array of Strings in The first ListView and when i click on an item in it, it displays the item i have selected in a textView. but each time i click another item it overides the last selection.     I would like to display each item that is clicked in a textView or Listview.
Hope that makes sense and any help is appreciated.

```
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {



                    String Exercise = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                    TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    textView3.setText(Exercise);

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the value set in the `TextView`. You need to append the values the way you want. 
If you want it to be separated by new line you can do this way -

Initialize your `TextView` only once -

```
private String result;
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

And change your `onItemClick()` -

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)     { 

                    String Exercise = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                   result = (textView3.getText().toString() + "\n" + Exercise;
                    textView3.setText(result);

                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm trying to get the value that is stored in the String Exercise each time i click. For example i have a list of Exercise "Squat", "DeadLift", "Bench Press". each time I click I want that value displayed so i end up with a list of two or three exercises. Sorry if this is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The text is ment to be appended in your string, then you set it to your textView and the string and textView are ment to me instantiated only onece in your onCreate method

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
String string ="";

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


string    += String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
 tv.setText(textView3.getText().toString() + "\n"); }
```

Comment: you are setting only new line character everytime

Comment: @shadab, are you trying to form a new list from the clicks you make each time

Answer (score 0):

I think textView.append() is the method you need.